# Racket 6.2 on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, dr.racket

Can someone please tell me whether the pre-built binary of Racket 6.2 (including Dr.Racket) will work on OS X 10.5.8?

Answer (score 2):

OS X 10.5 is the minimum supported version.

https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=users@racket-lang.org&q=subject:%22%5Bracket%5D+Minimum+OS+X+version+to+support%3F%22&o=newest&f=1